# Netbeans permission denied when running programs in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, netbeans, permissions

I'm trying to run a project written in C in Netbeans IDE in Ubuntu. The project is placed in my desktop. It compiles and builds it, but when trying to run it, the following message appears:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: /home/user/Desktop/Game generator/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/game_generator: Permission denied
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: it might be useful to ask this at askubuntu.com

Comment: quick solution would be running netbeans as root. or try `chmod -R 777 /home/user/Desktop/Game generator`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem while running a gradle project in Netbeans 8.1 IDE on ubuntu 14.04. So I tried to change project permissions with the following command:

```bush
sudo chmod -R 777 /{project_path}
```

Now it's working.